# Collection View Pin Cell With Different hight to top in a horizontal scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview

I have a horizontal collection view with different cell heights. By default the cells are centered in the middle of the collection view.

What I need is pin them to the top of the collection view not in the center so the extra space will be beneath the cells.

I have only one row with a total of 4 cells.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. Simply add this code in cellForItem method .

```
cell.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: cell.frame.minX, y: 0), size: cell.frame.size)
```

Also

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best solution is to override the flow layout and calculate every cell's frame.